# Can I get notifications for my favorite questions?

Tags: support

Is there any way to follow my favorite questions to get notifications (answer, comment) to my messages inbox such as the question I asked?

If there is not, could you add this feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's currently no way to get notifications for favourite questions (starred questions). You can mark favourite questions like this:

[image: Click star icon]

The ['favorites' tab](https://iot.stackexchange.com/users/current/?tab=favorites) in your profile will show you any activity on your favourite questions — the number on the tab increases, like this:

[image: Favourites tab icon]

<sup>Images from [Meta Stack Exchange's FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work)
 on favourite questions.</sup>

You don't get an inbox notification, but when you go to your profile and check, this will be indicated. When you click on the tab, the questions with recent activity will be near the top, and highlighted in yellow.

There is [a request to add notifications for favourites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83343/336144), but that was nearly 7 years ago, and it's still not implemented today. So, unfortunately, this seems unlikely to happen, and you'll have to use the alternative method I described above.

Comment: What about following a tag (e.g., Security) so I can receive notifications for it. I see this feature very interesting, and I saw it implemented in many other sites such as Quora

Comment: @BiG_TooTh You can either [set up a filter at stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/filters/) and get email notifications, or subscribe to the [tag:security] RSS feed (the link to the feed is at the bottom of the page). Unfortunately, inbox notifications in the top bar aren't available for this.